# roll effect for image before ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am working on a custom lightbox in which images next or previous is loaded via ajax calls. i want to achieve a effect before the ajax call is done so that the present image is rolled out before the ajax is called and the next image is loaded . here is my code for ajax

```
function loadimgagg(mipic){


var miid=$('#mipicview-overlay-content').attr('vwid')

var dataString = 'mipic='+ mipic+'&miid='+miid;

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "eg.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,

success: function(html){
$("#eg").html(html);
 }
 });
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Have you tried using the animation functions callback to call your ajax function. Take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/8Bcb7/

Comment: thanks for the demo friend , i am just trying for the roll out effect but no sucess plus any other method execpt beforeSend

Comment: oh, you said fadeout in your question...

Comment: yes ,but mainly i wanted to know about roll out as mentioned in question title too

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `beforeSend` callback in `$.ajax` :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "modules/gallery/miloader.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
beforeSend: function() {
// something here
},
success: function(html){
    $("#mipicview").html(html);
}
});
```

or you can do the effects before the ajax call :

```
function loadimgagg(mipic){
  var miid=$('#mipicview-overlay-content').attr('vwid')

  var dataString = 'mipic='+ mipic+'&miid='+miid;

 $('image').fadeOut( 100, function() { 
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "modules/gallery/miloader.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,

    success: function(html){
        $("#mipicview").html(html);
    }
 });  
})
```

Comment: any other soltuion then of beforeSend ?

Comment: when i try to use it before ajax call the effect dosen't even completes and nt image is loaded

Comment: @SakshiSharma try using it with a callback; like the one above (Updated).

Comment: but what for the roll out effect i want to achieve

Comment: You can just use animate instead of fadeOut, there are some great examples on the [jquery site](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: @SakshiSharma you may use any effect for the image roll out like i've `fadeOut` above. [jQuery effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Comment: i knw there is jquery website for it but no info on roll efect on it , using animate its possible but how . thats what i am asking

Comment: `$('#your_objects_id').animate({"left": "-=50px"}, "slow");` Just replace the values with how far/fast you want it to roll. By roll, do you actually mean slide?

Comment: http://glisse.victorcoulon.fr/example-2/ see this example click on image selecting roll . i want to achieve that

Comment: @SakshiSharma there are built in methods for `slideUp` & `slideDown` there but you can always roll left or right as commented by Jeemusu using the `animate()` method.

Comment: if i would have been so expert my friend then why would have i posted for help , atleast a simple working example that all i wanted a help with . so that i can understand and write a new one for my code later